# Где можно расшифровать этот текст?

Tags: python, decode

Я хочу расшифровать данный текст:

```
b'v10Z\x84:\xd4\xf3\xe8\x03\xfe\x1a\x89J\xee\xb9\x87)l9\xd4\xb4\x8b\'\xb7\xf4"\x06\xd3OkE\xcc\xf3\xbd?\xcamx\xed\xf1\xda\xda'
```

Я работаю с python и столкнулся с данной проблемой, не могли бы вы мне подсказать как декодиривать этот текст при помощи python

Comment: Не очень похоже на то. что там текст. А если там бинарные данные, то это они и есть, ничего декодировать не надо. P.S. Это точно не Unicode. Да и в однобайтной кодировке там куча непечатных символов `v10Z:ÔóèþJî¹)l9Ô´'·ô"ÓOkEÌó½?ÊmxíñÚÚ`.

Comment: Это массив байт. Вы уверенны что это текст? Если вы знаете кодировку, то тогда можно декодировать. Если нет, то можно перебором попробовать. Но не похоже, что это текст. Начинается с английских символов `v10Z`

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите все возможные условия для вашей задачи. В данном изложении результат не определен. Если у вас есть тест - пример с ответом, добавьте его.

Comment: @A_Vaclav Я знаю что содержимое этого массива `5a2988161297` но я хочу чтоб  мой python код мог узнать что там

Answer (score 0):

Это очень похоже на результат работы хэш-алгоритма 'shake_128'

```
import hashlib
    
gfg = hashlib.shake_128()
gfg.update(b'5a2988161297')
      
print(gfg.digest(40), ' - shake_128')

>>>b"v'\x8cD\x02\x05Lde\x85\x93\xb9:\xd2^\xb1\x1a\x160_\xb3\xc4\t\xcd\xe1\xf4\xf3\xbe|&#\xd7c\xf4\x9c.X\xc5\xe9 "  - shake_128
```

Отсюда вопрос... Зачем вам взламывать хэш-алгоритм

Comment: Я хотел чтоб программа могла сделать наоборот

Comment: Для того, что бы сделать "наоборот", нужны идентификаторы аппаратной части вычислительного комплекса, на котором считался хэш... я предполагаю... А так же я предполагаю, что ваши намерения ведут в криминальную зону. Не надо этого делать, пожалуйста.