# Где можно расшифровать этот массив байт?

Tags: python, массивы, decode

Я хочу расшифровать данный массив байт:

```
b'v10Z\x84:\xd4\xf3\xe8\x03\xfe\x1a\x89J\xee\xb9\x87)l9\xd4\xb4\x8b\'\xb7\xf4"\x06\xd3OkE\xcc\xf3\xbd?\xcamx\xed\xf1\xda\xda'
```

Я работаю с python и столкнулся с данной проблемой, не могли бы вы мне подсказать как декодиривать или прочитать этот массив при помощи python

Comment: А [дубли-то](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1350591/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82) зачем плодить?

Comment: @CILSH Убедительная просьба, не задавайте один и тот же вопрос дважды, в противном случае он будет заморожен

Comment: Дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1350591/Где-можно-расшифровать-этот-текст